# Trying to fetch data, and the data field is titled "description-3". What is proper syntax of {items.description-3}?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

If I try and type it in directly, it gives me NaN. How do I include "description-3" since it has special character "-"?

```
return <FlatList data={data.items} renderItem= {({item}) => {
        return(
            <View>
            <Text>{item.description-3}</Text>
            </View>
        )}}/>;
```

Comment: This needs more detail. I am flagging as needs more detail.

Comment: it's a very simple question

Comment: But we need to know your code. What have you done? We can't answer your question without all those details.

Comment: does this help?

Comment: Yes definitely. This is already much better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bracket notation when there are special characters in your properties names

```
item["description-3"]
```